# load IonPopover onclick from antoher file

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, onclick, popover, buttonclick

i´m trying to load the Component "IonPopover" via Button-click from the external file "showPopUp.tsx".

This is the line, where im trying to load the external Component "IonPopover" via "onClick()". The external "ShowPopup()" function is called successfully so far and also the if-condition gets passed, but the return of the Component "IonPopover" its not working.
Hope someone can help me.

file: ListUserTask.tsx

```
import ShowPopup from "./showPopup";


                                        <IonButton
                                            fill="outline"
                                            slot="end" 
                                            onClick={() => ShowPopup(true)}
                                        >
                                            Details
                                        </IonButton>
```

file:showPopUp.tsx

```
import { IonButton, IonPopover } from "@ionic/react";
import React from "react";

function ShowPopup(props: any): JSX.Element {
    if (props) {
        console.log("INSIDE");
        return (
            <div className="showpopup">
                <IonPopover className="popup">
                    showPopup
                    <IonButton className="close-btn">Schliessen</IonButton>
                    {props.children}
                </IonPopover>
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        throw new Error("TRIGGER FALSE");
    }
}
export default ShowPopup;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about react but in Angular, we use

```
router.navigate(["your page route for popup"],state: {variableName: value});
```

This variableName can be assigned a value as true/false and then in other file, you can give a condition that popover opens when variableName is true.